# Convert a DataFrame to Pandas Pivot table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, data-manipulation

I have the data in the Pandas DataFrame in the below format:
[image]

Now I want to convert it into the below format with pandas:
[image]

Can someone please help.

The data should be for all the Referrer Type with the count and Device Type will contain the Column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), passing the columns you want to keep to `id_vars`:

```py
pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Brand", "Referrer Type"])
```